# Multiplying columns x-end while maintaining file structure

Tags: text-processing, awk, files, osx

I have as an input File1 which looks like this:

```
A,22,1,2,3,4,5
G,26,5,6,7
X,28,10,20,10
```

I would like to apply an equation to columns 3-end while maintaining file structure. For example if the equation I want use is multiplying by 2 I am looking for the output:

```
A,22,2,4,6,8,10
G,26,10,12,14
X,28,20,40,20
```

I attempted to do this with the following command:

```
awk -F ',' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i >= 3)
     print 2*$i
  else
    print $i }' File1
```

This provides the correct output but gets rid of all file structure. If of use the actual equation I am looking to use is: 2*(2*($i-1)+1)

Any explanations accompanying a solution is much appreciated since I am still quite new to this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to set the output field separator (`OFS`), e.g.:

```
awk '{ for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) $i*=2 } 1' FS=, OFS=, infile
```

Or using your formula:

```
awk '{ for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) $i = 2*(2*($i-1)+1) } 1' FS=, OFS=, infile
```

Output:

```
A,22,2,4,6,8,10
G,26,10,12,14
X,28,20,40,20
```

The `1` at the end of the script is a short-hand for `{ print $0 }`

Comment: Thank you @Thor! This maintains structure as wanted. Now my issue is that using the math function. I see how you are doing simple multiplication but don't see how to apply my more complicated formula 2*(2*($i-1)+1)

Comment: @DNA_bash hint: `$i *= 2` is just shorthand for `$i = $i * 2`.

Comment: @DNA_bash: added an example

Answer (score 2):

`Perl` can tackle like as shown:
Based on the suggestion by @Thor:

```
$ perl -F, -anE '$,="," ; say splice(@F,0,2), map { 2*(2*($_-1)+1) } @F' inp.csv
```

Using another approach:

```
$ perl -lpe '
   /^[^,]*,[^,]*/g; #positions the search engine before the 2nd comma.
   s/\G,\K([^,]*)/2*(2*($1-1)+1)/ge;
' inp.csv
```

The GNU desk calculator utility can do it as:

```
$ < inp.csv tr ',-'  ' _' | sed -Ee 's/\S+/[&]/' |
    dc -e "
     [q]sq
     [44an]s,
     [1-2*1+2*]s=
     [SM lN1+sN z0<a]sa
     [LMnl,x LMnl,x lN2-sN]sb
     [LMl=xn lN1<, lN1-dsN0<c]sc
     [?z0=q 0sN lax lbx lcx 10an z0=?]s?
     l?x
"
```

These are simple utilities and explanations upon request as these are simple n straightforward codes.

**Brief explanation:**

The `dc` utility works on a stack where it stores its data n code. From here it stores  n retrieves in registers.

String data is quoted in square brackets.

Lopping is done via recursion.

In this dc code there are 7 registers storing code, viz.,   q   =  ,   a    b    c  ?

The two registers M   N  store data.

Work backwards from end. The code register ? performs the action of
       reading the next line from input. Then compares how many space separated items are on its stack; think of them as fields. In case 0 , stop n quit. z0=q snippet does that. It reads as: z is dc command to return the number of elements present. That us compared with 0 and if equal, the code stored in register q is executed.

Comment: There's nothing simple about the syntax of sed or perl :) You need to know quite a bit of perl to understand this code, you're using a lot of perl tricks here. And perl I know well enough to get what you're doing, the `dc` commands look like magic incantations!

Comment: Your `map` solution could also be: `perl -F, -anE '$,=","; say @F[0 .. 1], map { $_ * 2 } @F[2 .. $#F]'`

Comment: or rather `2*(2*($_-1)+1)`

Answer (score -1):

```
s=`awk '{print NR}' p.txt| sort -nr | sed -n '1p'`
praveen@praveen:~$ for ((i=1;i<=$s;i++)); do m=`awk -v i="$i" -F "," 'NR==i{print NF}' p.txt`; for ((u=1;u<=$m;u++)); do if [[ $u < 3 ]]; then awk -v  i="$i" -v  u="$u" -F ","  'NR==i{print $u}'  p.txt; else awk -v i="$i" -v u="$u" -F "," 'NR==i {print 2*$u}' p.txt; fi; done| sed "N;s/\n/,/g"| sed "N;s/\n/,/g"| sed "N;s/\n/,/g"; done

where p.txt is filename



A,22,2,4,6,8,10
G,26,10,12,14
X,28,20,40,20
```